# Missing Exif data Filepond Vue after save

Tags: exif, filepond

After saving image to server - images missing some exif data (Latitude Long)
Here is info after save
In real image is full exif

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please share your code, error, or give more context on your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property `imageTransformOutputStripImageHead` to `false`.

See docs here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-transform/#properties